# Pulling nested URL endpoints in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, fetch, es6-promise

I have been playing around with the Star Wars API and I'm having a hard time trying to pull in the Film data from the characters (https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/).

> ```
> export const SwapiFilms = (props) => {
>   const [films, setFilms] = useState([]);
>
>   const filmList = props.filmsUrl;
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     function getData() {
>       try {
>         const response = Promise.all(
>           filmList.map((url) => 
>             fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
>           )
>         );
>         console.log(response);
>         setFilms(response);
>       } catch (error) {
>         console.log(error);
>       }
>     }
>
>     getData();
>   }, []);
>
>   return (
>     <>
>       Title: {films.title}
>       <br />
>       <br />
>       Director: {films.director}
>       <br />
>       <br />
>       {JSON.stringify(films)}
>     </>
>   );
> };
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `await` the `Promise.all`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function getData() { // <-- declare getData an async function
    try {
      const response = await Promise.all( // <-- await promise resolution
        filmList.map((url) => 
          fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
        )
      );
      console.log(response);
      setFilms(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  getData();
}, []);
```

You probably shouldn't mix promise chaining and async/await either. Stick with one or the other

Promise Chain

```
useEffect(() => {
  Promise.all(filmList.map(fetch))
    .then(responses => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error('Film response not ok!');
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(films => {
      console.log(films);
      setFilms(films);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}, []);
```

Async/Await

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function getData() {
    try {
      const responses = await Promise.all(filmList.map(fetch));
      const films = await Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json());

      console.log(films);
      setFilms(films);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  getData();
}, []);
```

***Side Note**: your films state is an array, so you'll want to access `films` using array methods in your render return.*

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Rendering the array is something I forgot about.